# Install twitter gem on windows7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

Trying to setup a windows development machine for a Rails project that has a dependency on the twitter gem.

I get an error when I try and do gem install twitter.

It needs to build native extensions and using --platform=mswin32 didn't work like for other GEMs

Using ubuntu is really not an option.  I need the computer I am using for too many other windows things.

Comment: no idea why someone voted this down, +1

Comment: Based on some other research and the lack of any real solution here, I looked at the commit history for the twitter gem on github and installed version 0.9.4 which worked.  Not really doing much with twitter and I just need this system to do some light development mostly on the UI side so it worked for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably heard this before, but as you get more seriously into ruby stuff, you are going to run into more and more issues running ruby on windows.

That being said, if all you need is to compile, head over to http://rubyinstaller.org and install your ruby through the provided installer. After that is done, hit "Add Ons" off of the main page, and download the dev kit. Extract that in your ruby directory, and you should now be able to build native extensions.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try.  I do my primary development on OSX, but this is for my wife to do some mostly UI stuff for me.  I had her using an old Ubuntu system I had, but it really wasn't powerful enough.  I don't want to wipe her system out or push into a dual boot scenario just yet

Comment: I personally avoid windows as much as is possible and insisted on a project a few years ago that all the developers switch to linux, which they did.  But in this case it's my wife's new laptop and she kind of likes windows.  She doesn't have an aversion to using linux, just a preference for windows and this task is not her primary use of the computer.